# The Hat Problem: why use PIE?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, derangements

> Suppose that each of $n$ men at a party throws his hat into the center of the room. The hats are first mixed up, and then each man randomly selects a hat. What is the probability that
>
> (a) None of the men selects his own hat;

In this question, I know that the answer given uses Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion (PIE), but I have the following solution. Could someone please explain why this does not work and how I am supposed to figure out for other such questions when to use my way, and when to use PIE?

|Probability Space| = n! ways of arranging
|Event that every person gets any hat that is not theirs| =
Step 1: Person 1 picks any hat other than theirs in n-1 ways
Step 2: Person 2 picks any hat other than theirs and the hat already picked in (n-1)-1=n-2 ways...and so on. Total cardinality for the event = (n-1)!

Therefore P = (n-1)!/n!

Comment: But what if person 1 picked person 2's hat? Then it is (n-1) ways for person 2, not (n-2). It is one of the many such nuances you will get into. That is why derangement solution through PIE.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Could I have general tips about how to think of such nuances?

Answer (score 3):

What if the first person picked the second person's hat and then the second person has got $n-1$ instead of $n-2$ ways to pick a hat that is not his own.

Comment: For some reason, I assumed that this possibility would be covered in my calculation. I guess it's not. Thank you!!

Comment: +1 for beating Math Lover to the punch.